# How can I uncenter the address field in the Safari toolbar on macOS 10.15 Catalina?

Tags: macos, safari, catalina

I updated to macOS Catalina, and discovered that in Safari's toolbar, the URL/address field now appears to be centered no matter what I do. This leads to an uneven appearance:

[image]

When I edit the toolbar, it doesn't seem to matter if I put flexible spaces around the field—the address field always ends up centered. I don't believe this was the behavior before macOS Catalina. It's unclear to me whether this is the designed behavior now, or whether it's due to something I did (or perhaps a defaults setting I set long ago).

Preemptive answers to likely comments:

1. yes, I know Catalina is not the latest version of macOS
2. yes, I can rearrange the other icons in the toolbar, but this question is specifically about the location of the address field.

**Is there a way to make the URL field end up placed naturally, based on the flow of the other icons and spaces in the toolbar, rather than always have it end up in the middle**?

Comment: Seems to do the same right back to El Capitan.

Comment: @Tetsujin In Mojave 10.14.6, the address bar is definitely _not_ forced to stay in the middle. I am looking at copy of Safari running in Mojave as I type this. I was easily able to edit the toolbar to remove a space, and the address bar shifted left. Screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/L1XAQ8Q7AiOW.png

Answer (score 4):

Not easily. Apple has hard coded the arrangement so that if you drag the address text entry to the left of the flexible space it still centers things.

Unless there’s a hidden setting to add fixed space or shim or patch safari in a way that doesn’t run afoul of code signing and SIP you likely have to choose a different browser.

You did not cause this - it’s repeatable out-of-the-box behavior on Catalina and Big Sur and Monterey.